# Articles in general speaking

Tags: articles

> The cat is a small, furry animal with four legs and a tail.

> A mobile phone is a portable telephone that can make and receive calls
> over a radio frequency link while the user is moving within a
> telephone service area.

> The donut is a small, circular cake, fried in hot fat, either with a hole in the middle or filled with jam.

Why is the definite article  used in the first sentence  but not in the second and the third ones, since  we talk about any cat, any phone and any donut, or, in other words, about the categories "cat"/"phone"/"donut"?

Comment: There's possibly a reasonable question here, but some seem to think that the choice of which generic construction to use is pretty arbitrary. I'll give my thinking. 'The' in the first sentence seems to pay a certain respect or at least familiarity to the often-loved critter. 'A' seems less personal, more formal, and more harmonious with the technoblurb that follows.

Comment: Related: [Definite article and generic uses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198824/the-definite-article-implying-the-generic-idea-of-something)

Comment: It's a common usage to refer to an animal with the definite article to mean 'the species in general'.

Comment: One more example: The donut is a small, circular cake, fried in hot fat, either with a hole in the middle or filled with jam.

Comment: What if the doughnut has cream filling?

Comment: What does it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GENERAL
1)
**The cat** is a small, furry animal with four legs and a tail.
**A cat** is a small, furry animal with four legs and a tail.
**Cats** are small, furry animals with four legs and a tail.

2)
**A mobile phone** is a portable telephone that can make and receive calls.
**Mobile phones** are portable telephone that can make and receive calls.
**The mobile phone** etc. same thing.
3)
The donut is a small, circular cake, fried in hot fat, either with a hole in the middle or filled with jam.

Same thing: "A donut is" or "Donuts are".

General Style:

When talking about **a category of animal or thing**, one can use the to indicate the category:

**The lion is a noble beast.**

That use of "the" is **more formal**. However, the meaning of the example with the and the meaning using **A lion** or **Lions** would be the same thing. If you were writing a science article about a genus of plant, you would probably use:

**The lily** is native to [etc]. For example. Rather than Lilies or A lily.

**The mobile telephone was a late, 20th c. invention.**

Lastly, in speaking, one does not generally use the "the" version unless you are giving a speech.